# Error.. Converting date into corresponding days

Tags: python, datetime

I wanted to convert date into corresponding days

The column 'date' looks like below

```
0         2018-01-01 
1         2018-01-02
2         2018-01-03
```

My code:

```
import datetime
for i in df['date']:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%A')
    print(i)
```

I received error message

```
" unconverted data remains"
```

I researched similar topics but cannot find solutions, any suggestions? 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2018-11-01', "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%A')
'Thursday'
```

you can check your dict

Comment: Thanks, i know how to it individually but I have a long list of dates so I want to use loop

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense to me - if the dates look like `0         2018-01-01 `, they can't be parsed with that format string - the error OP is getting is a result of trying to parse with the wrong format string. The values have to have everything but the date stripped out first. Of course that format string would work if the dates were in the correct format, but the issue is getting them into the correct format in the first place. At least that's how I see it.